# Safe to enable LARGEADDRESSAWARE in 32bit Qt5 app?

Tags: qt, 32bit-64bit, qwebengineview

Does anyone knows if it's safe to set LARGEADDRESSAWARE on a 32bit application using Qt-5.6 and Qt WebEngine?

I mean, I believe qt normally should be able to handle those large address spaces, right?

Thanks,
Mont3z.

Comment: I believe the `.dlls` of `Qt` would have had to be compiled with this setting for it to work.

Comment: thx for your reply.